# Как дату из строки вида "2024-03-24" перевести в datetime.date

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу телеграм бота. Бот проверяет подписку у пользователей по дате , но не могу сравнить 2024-03-24 допустим с 2024-03-22 , поскольку одно вида str а другое вида datetime.date как преобразовать str в datetime.date, либо наоборот.Заранее спасибо,не программист)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это стандартный ISO формат даты (см. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), для его парсинга есть специальный метод:

```
from datetime import date
d = date.fromisoformat("2024-03-22")
```

В обратную сторону — можно просто функцию `str` использовать:

```
from datetime import date
d = date(2024, 3, 22)
s = str(d)
```

Или методом `isoformat`:

```
from datetime import date
d = date(2024, 3, 22)
s = d.isoformat()
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ